# How to consolidate in a query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help writing a query to consolidate names into a list that are associated with a foreign key. Here's my current query,

```
select distinct concat(c_first, ' ', c_last) as name, pmt_no 
from disbursements d
left join contacts c on c.c_no = d.b_no
where d.ba_no = 1
```

**My result set looks like this**

```
Louis Vaz, 586014

Antionette An, 690682

Brian Cald, 690682

Mark Brian, 3233902
```

**My desired outcome is**

```
Louis Vaz, 586014

Antionette An - Brian Cald, 690682

Mark Brian, 3233902
```

Please note that both the people with pmt_no 690682 are now joined together with a '-' separating them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function to achieve what you want:

```
select group_concat(distinct concat(c_first, ' ', c_last) SEPARATOR ' - ') as name, pmt_no 
from disbursements d
left join contacts c on c.c_no = d.b_no
where d.ba_no = 1
group by pmt_no
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `group_concat()` along with a `group_by`:

```
select group_concat(c_first, ' ', c_last separator ' - ') as names,
       pmt_no 
from disbursements d left join
     contacts c 
     on c.c_no = d.b_no
where d.ba_no = 1
group by pmt_no;
```